# How to expand layout in android depending on the screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I need to create 6 images or button like its shown on blue cells on picture, action bar alredy exist, black is the picture that exist and ad banner exist and it works well. So I need to add 6 blue cells-images. 
This is the old code

[image: img]

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
tools:context=".Activity_Home" 

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/top_bar" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottomlayout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <!--
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:contentDescription="app_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/dashboard_image" />
        -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_not_connected"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_2"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <!-- I removed this ListView -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/event_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code that I have created:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
tools:context=".Activity_Home" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/top_bar" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottomlayout" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <!--
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:contentDescription="app_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/dashboard_image" />
        -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_not_connected"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_2"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <!-- I have added this GridLayout and ImageViews in it  -->
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/img_exibhome" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/img_exibhome" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/img_exibhome" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/img_loginticket" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/img_loginticket" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/img_loginticket" />

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the task is to remove listview content and add the six cells as I shown at the pic in blue cells. I have tried to do it in gridlayout, it works good on phone, but not on tablet, on tablet it distortioned the 6 images. So my question is how can I achieve the task so it fits to all screens, should I do it programatically? Also idea is that if ad banner is not present, the Ui components should stretch to occupy the space of missing add banner. Is that possibly to create in xml or also that should be done programatically?

Comment: Use GridLayoutManager with RecycleView. There are lots of examples online (https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

Comment: Thanks for quick response ;). Should I use RecycleView although I need fix number of cells?

Comment: `GridLayout` is all you need for fixed cells.

Comment: Thx cricket. Can you give me the hint how to programatically do option with and without ad banner?